# 301 редирект ссылок Joomla

Tags: redirect, joomla

Здравствуйте, переношу сайт с  Joomla на другой движок и возникла проблема с URL. Новую версию сайта ещё не перенёс и на временном хостинге тестирую ёё 301 редиректом. Всё это делается для того чтоб потом перегнать вес страых страниц на новые с новыми URL. Проблема в том, что используя следующую запись:

> Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_joomap&Itemid=18 http://site.ru/map.html

меня перенаправляет на главную страницу и в URL остаётся "хвост" параметров т.е. вот так:

> http://site.ru/about.html?option=com_joomap&Itemid=18

Есть ли способ это исправить? Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал вот такую конструкцию для каждой страницы 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_joomap&Itemid=18
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://site.ru/map.html [L,R=301]

А затем после всех редиректов использовал вот такую запись:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^?]*)\? 
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

Она удаляет ВСЕ добавочные параметры в URL на всех страницах сайта. В моём случае помогло, но если у вас имеются страницы, у которых есть параметры в URL, ВАМ ЭТО НЕ ПОМОЖЕТ!